# Remove certain dataframes from list, with condition on column headers. Without duplicating list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of 10 dataframes(number may change). About 8 of these dataframes have the same headers. However 2 do not. This ratios is also subject to change. I require to keep the 8 tables in the list, while deleting the other 2.

I am trying to find a solution without **duplicating my complete list**.

At the moment this is what I am trying:

```
for indx,tabl in enumerate(table_list):
        print(indx)
        check= list(table_list[indx])
        if 'Date' not in check:
            del table_list[indx]
```

However, This is skipping certain indexes. Because I am deleting within the loop.

**Please note : DATE is one of the columns in the 8 tables that I would like to keep**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get frequency of headers, then use list comprehension to filter:

```
from collections import Counter

# Example setup
l = [pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'], 'A': np.random.randint(0, 10, 2), 'B': np.random.randint(0, 10, 2)}) for i in range(8)]
l += [pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'], 'A': np.random.randint(0, 10, 2)}) for i in range(2)]

print(l)

# [         Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  5  1
# 1  2020-01-02  3  8,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  0  9
# 1  2020-01-02  4  6,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  5  8
# 1  2020-01-02  7  8,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  9  8
# 1  2020-01-02  2  6,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  6  1
# 1  2020-01-02  9  6,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  8  3
# 1  2020-01-02  8  2,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  3  3
# 1  2020-01-02  6  6,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  5  0
# 1  2020-01-02  7  8,           foo  A
# 0  2020-01-01  4
# 1  2020-01-02  6,           foo  A
# 0  2020-01-01  5
# 1  2020-01-02  8]
```

---

```
# Get most common headers
headers = Counter([tuple(df) for df in l])
frequent_header = max(headers, key=lambda key: headers[key])

# Filter with list comprehension
l = [df for df in l if tuple(df) == frequent_header]

print(l)

# [         Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  5  1
# 1  2020-01-02  3  8,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  0  9
# 1  2020-01-02  4  6,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  5  8
# 1  2020-01-02  7  8,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  9  8
# 1  2020-01-02  2  6,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  6  1
# 1  2020-01-02  9  6,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  8  3
# 1  2020-01-02  8  2,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  3  3
# 1  2020-01-02  6  6,          Date  A  B
# 0  2020-01-01  5  0
# 1  2020-01-02  7  8]
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to save the list of indexes to delete, and delete them afterwards.

```py
to_be_rm = []
for indx,tabl in enumerate(table_list):
    check= list(table_list[indx])
    if 'Date' not in check:
        to_be_rm.append(indx)

for idx in to_be_rm:
    table_list.pop(idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task should be performed in 3 steps:

- Find the list of required columns - I decided to take the longest
  column list from lists containing *Date*, actually - I generate a
  set of them.
- Generate the OK_list - loop again over the table list and check whether
  the current DataFrame contains all required columns.
- Generate the new list - copying only those DataFrames, which are included
  in the ok_list.

The code to do it can be as follows:

```
# Find the longest column list
req_cols = {}
lgth_req_cols = 0
for indx, tabl in enumerate(table_list):
    cols = set(tabl.columns)
    lgth = len(cols)
    if lgth > lgth_req_cols and 'Date' in cols:
        req_cols = cols
        lgth_req_cols = lgth
# Generate OK_list (which DataFrames to leave)
ok_list = []
for indx, tabl in enumerate(table_list):
    cols = set(tabl.columns)
    if len(req_cols.intersection(cols)) == lgth_req_cols:
        ok_list.append(indx)
# Generate the new list
new_table_list = [ table_list[i] for i in ok_list ]
```

I decided to save the "shrinked" list under a new variable, but if you
want, you can overwrite the original *table_list*.

This code would be shorter if you had the required column list in advance,
but since you wrote nothing about it, I assumed that you have no such list.